# Primality test for generalized Fermat numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, counterexamples, elementary-proofs

This question is successor of [Primality test for specific class of generalized Fermat numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/173036/88804) .

Can you provide a proof or a counterexample for the claim given below?

Inspired by [Lucas–Lehmer–Riesel primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer%E2%80%93Riesel_test) I have formulated the following claim:

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$ . 
>   Let $F_n(b)= b^{2^n}+1 $ where $b$ is an even natural number and $n\ge2$ . Let $a$ be a natural number greater than two such that $\left(\frac{a-2}{F_n(b)}\right)=-1$ and $\left(\frac{a+2}{F_n(b)}\right)=-1$ where $\left(\frac{}{}\right)$ denotes Jacobi symbol. Let $S_i=P_b(S_{i-1})$ with $S_0$ equal to the modular $P_{b/2}(P_{b/2}(a))\phantom{5} \text{mod} \phantom{5} F_n(b)$. Then $F_n(b)$ is prime if and only if $S_{2^n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{F_n(b)}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJylk8Fu2zAMhu99CtbAamlS09nDLnUFDBvW03bbrW0CyWFioY5kSHKSIci7j3XcNcVyKFCdRBL_x1-UtOwmuNYtyxLGxIx0XO1ulZmWUyeKSqvP1aaxLbJz9hi8w_oRA9OXpbzlSl0WcHEBR3nxnOdSC8GrqH75OSs_dr6tGzR_YoNrZq5KWcgTKX1Vck6Aqk5BFWNf2t8oMkMtT9NIGEk46oQqeBUw9cGxyPcZP5vjAr43ZHA43PUZ0LILMB9KpYpD-LRGzU-dcPtj2wWW3d_TNu2-6Yiw6mMCg6Ad4BoduH5lMJwTnw8EbAnpbso38Nw_2DIgVQOkhrA0w2NcxBcUoZfdZNG7OlnvZrVux-vK5B2d6YFPol4io8F_ehGd9BBTYIaLbLorp5l4inZuT_E-E8_2RAE2Qhfs6sjP_57eh6_9qvPRprHFV-toDrpOw2XNmFHWdX2aGb9lpcwNXOdyY-epUcUXLt3rqntd1cOQVMQW6-QDu8uHy88fpOlT8i6q36FH2WqDrcpzPr6IgwwUDJ_hEHEYSrHxGxhTwxvifwF2i_nT&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==). A list of generalized Fermat primes sorted by base $b$ can be found [here](http://jeppesn.dk/generalized-fermat.html). I have tested this claim for many random values of $b$ and $n$ and there were no counterexamples.

A command line program that implements this test can be found [here](https://github.com/PedjaTerzic/Fermat).

Android app that implements this test can be found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VLH8WVT) .

Python script that implements this test can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/PedjaTerzic/10b0425b4ed01e149db28ca964830499).

Mathematica notebook that implements this test can be found [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/princeps37/Published/Fermat.cdf).

Comment: There are no counterexamples for $b \in [2,10000]$ with $n \in [2,10]$ .

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial answer.

This answer proves that if $F_n(b)$ is prime, then $S_{2^n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{F_n(b)}$.

*Proof* :

Let $N:=F_n(b)=b^{2^n}+1$. It can be proven by induction that
$$S_i\equiv 2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(p^{b^{i+2}/4}+q^{b^{i+2}/4})\pmod N\tag1$$
where $p=a-\sqrt{a^2-4},q=a+\sqrt{a^2-4}$.

From $(1)$, we get, using $\sqrt{a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4}}=\frac 1{\sqrt 2}(\sqrt{a+2}\pm\sqrt{a-2})$,

$$\begin{align}&2^{N+1}\cdot S_{2^n-2}^2-2^{N+2}
\\\\&\equiv \left(\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{a-2}\right)\left(\sqrt{a+2}-\sqrt{a-2}\right)^{N}
\\&\qquad\qquad +\left(\sqrt{a+2}-\sqrt{a-2}\right)\left(\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{a-2}\right)^{N}\pmod N
\\\\&\equiv \sqrt{a+2}\left(\left(\sqrt{a+2}-\sqrt{a-2}\right)^{N}
+\left(\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{a-2}\right)^{N}\right)
\\&\qquad\qquad-\sqrt{a-2}\left(\left(\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{a-2}\right)^{N}
-\left(\sqrt{a+2}-\sqrt{a-2}\right)^{N}\right)\pmod N
\\\\&\equiv \sqrt{a+2}\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom Nk(\sqrt{a+2})^{N-k}((-\sqrt{a-2})^k+(\sqrt{a-2})^k)
\\&\qquad\qquad -\sqrt{a-2}\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom Nk(\sqrt{a+2})^{N-k}((\sqrt{a-2})^k-(-\sqrt{a-2})^k)\pmod N
\\\\&\equiv \sum_{j=0}^{(N-1)/2}\binom{N}{2j}(a+2)^{(N-2j+1)/2}\cdot 2(a-2)^j
\\&\qquad\qquad -\sum_{j=1}^{(N+1)/2}\binom{N}{2j-1}(a+2)^{(N-2j+1)/2}\cdot 2(a-2)^j\pmod N
\\\\&\equiv 2(a+2)\cdot\left(\frac{a+2}{N}\right)-2(a-2)\cdot\left(\frac{a-2}{N}\right)\pmod N
\\\\&\equiv 2(a+2)\cdot (-1)-2(a-2)\cdot (-1)\pmod N
\\\\&\equiv -8\pmod N
\end{align}$$
So, we get
$$2^{N+1}\cdot S_{2^n-2}^2-2^{N+2}\equiv -8\pmod N$$
It follows from $2^{(N-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod N$ that
$$S_{2^n-2}\equiv 0\pmod{F_n(b)}$$